# Updating a managedObject in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity, nsfetchrequest

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:**

In one splitview, I have a a tableview as its master, and a UIView as the detail. The tableview has 2 columns: "Days" and then "Sessions". I get the data from the Core Data, the entities called "Sessions". When I click on a "Session" tableviewcell, the detailview gets updated.

In the detailview, I added an "Add" button in the navigation bar. When you click on this, I add a new entity called "NewSession" to the core data.

```
if ([_sessionData.added isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]) {

        [_sessionData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"added"];

    SessionData *session = (SessionData*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewSessions" inManagedObjectContext:[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton].managedObjectContext];

    session.startDate = _sessionData.startDate;
    session.endDate = _sessionData.endDate;
    session.sessionLocation = nil;
    session.sessionTitle = _sessionData.sessionTitle;
    session.sessionDescription = _sessionData.sessionDescription;
    [session setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"added"];

    _addButton =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Remove" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil] autorelease];
    NSError *error = nil;

            if (![[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton].managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                DebugLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"SESSION ALREADY ADDED");
    }
```

ANOTHER splitview's tableview fetches the "NewSession" entity, and gets all the data and displays it.

**THE PROBLEM:**

Whenever I exit the application and relaunch it, the sessions in the other splitview are still there, BUT I can add the SAME session again.

In the "add" code, I have the following:

```
[_sessionData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"added"];
```

Now, my sessionData is an NSManagedObject; and I thought that just setting the values will update them in the core data.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but *similar* doesn't mean *the same*. I don't know if it works for you but you can try it. This method was described to me by @macbirdie and it works for me.

**First of all, import your AppDelegate header file**:

```
#import "YourAppDelegate.h"
```

**Then, update your code:**

```
if ([_sessionData.added isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]) {

    [_sessionData setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"added"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] managedObjectContext];

    SessionData *session = (SessionData*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewSessions" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    session.startDate = _sessionData.startDate;
    session.endDate = _sessionData.endDate;
    session.sessionLocation = nil;
    session.sessionTitle = _sessionData.sessionTitle;
    session.sessionDescription = _sessionData.sessionDescription;
    session.added = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

    _addButton =  [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Remove" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil] autorelease];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(saveMoc:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:moc];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![moc save:&error]) {
        DebugLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

} else {
    NSLog(@"SESSION ALREADY ADDED");
}
```

**And add this methode somewhere in your file**:

```
- (void)saveMoc:(NSNotification *)notification {
    YourAppDelegate *appDel = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDel.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```